# JavaScript, функции, которые вызываются при объявлении

Tags: javascript

В чем разница между такими двумя вариантами?

```
(function doSmth() {
  ...
})();

(function doSmth() {
  ...
}());
```

Comment: нет разницы между вариантами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данные два варианта являются [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), которые тут же выполняются.

И единственное отличие - порядок скобок. Больше они ничем не отличаются.